# Why "switch(true){}" in php with a strange logic?

Tags: php

```
switch(false) {
    case 'blogHitd':
        echo('ddd');
        break;
    case false:
        echo('bbbb');
        break;
    default:
        echo 'alert("error action");';
 }
```

*-------output------*

*bbbb*

```
switch(true) {
    case 'blogHitd':
        echo('ddd');        
        break;
    case true:
        echo('bbbb');
        break;
     default:
        echo 'alert("error action");';
 }
```

*-------a strange output-------*

*ddd*

Why, when I pass the value of `true` it will always select the first one?

Comment: a string is true, so you see "ddd" and then you call break to exit switch

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the PHP documentation on [Booleans](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php):

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>
> - the boolean FALSE itself
> - the integer 0 (zero)
> - the float 0.0 (zero)
> - the empty string, and the string "0"
> - an array with zero
>   elements
> - an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
> - the special
>   type NULL (including unset variables
> - SimpleXML objects created from
>   empty tags
>
> Every other value is considered TRUE (including any resource).

The last sentence of this quoted passage is the line of interest in your case.

Answer (score 27):

Switching "true" is only useful if you've got functions or variables in your "case" line

```
switch(true)
{
  case is_array($array):
    echo 'array';
    break;
  default:
    echo 'something else';
    break;
}
```

Comment: In my case this is what the person was doing in the code I inherited.  Such a strange way of doing things.

Comment: It can sometimes make the code more readable than a long list if `if` ... `else if`, e.g. if this example is extended cover `is_object`, `is_string` etc., and perhaps if it is returning the value instead of `echo`ing it so there's no need for the `break;`.

Answer (score 6):

Note that switch/case does loose comparision.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose

Answer (score 3):

PHP will typecast values for you, don't forget:

```
php > var_dump(true == 'bloghitd');
bool(true)
```

Answer (score 2):

In this scenario the **switch** only runs the first valid case.

It is useful in the case that you have more than one possible answer but you want to run only the first one. For example:

```
switch(true){
 case 1 == 2:
   echo '1 == 2';
   break;

 case 2 == 2:
   echo '2 == 2';
   break;

 case 3 == 3:
   echo '3 == 3';
   break;

 case 4 == 1:
   echo '4 == 1';
   break;
}
```

The output:
*2 == 2*

Both the second and third cases are true, but we only get the second (which is the first TRUE).

Comment: That's the role of "break;", remove it and it keeps going!