# Evaluating a switch expression at runtime in C

Tags: c, switch-statement

I want to read characters from the console and check if it is alpha numeric. From my understanding, `isalnum` has the following function signature.

`int isalnum(int x);`

Why is it illegal to write

`switch(input) {
    case isalnum(input):
        ...`

if `isalnum` returns an integer value.

Comment: `case` values must be constants or literals.

Comment: try switch(isalnum(input)) - case 1: - case: 0

Comment: Why not `if(isalnum(input)) { ... }`?

Comment: @BeyelerStudios The purpose of the exercise i'm working on is to use switch statements.

Comment: @emsimpson92, you mean `case 0:` and `default:`

Comment: ah... I'm used to C# where default: isn't required.

Comment: @emsimpson92, in c `default` is also optional, but I mean `isalnum` return value is _A value **different from zero** (i.e., true) if indeed c is either a digit or a letter. Zero (i.e., false) otherwise._

Comment: To the OP, there's probably some benefit in learning exactly how a `switch` operates in C.  Even if this were possible, it probably would not do what you want anyway.  At a wild guess you're trying to do what Scuzzy's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829229/why-switchtrue-in-php-with-a-strange-logic) shows.  That's possible in PHP, but it is simply not possible in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/switch

The syntax requires

> **case** *constant_expression* **:** *statement*

with

> *constant_expression* -   a constant expression of the same type as the type of condition after conversions and integral promotions

I.e. syntax requires constant expression.
The result of a function call is not a constant expression.
That is why it is illegal.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call isalnum in your case statement. Try something like this:

```
switch(isalnum(input))
{
  case 0:
    //do stuff
    break;
  default:
    //do other stuff
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have explained the requirements of C syntax, specifically that each `case` value needs to be a constant expression.  I just want to add that the example code you presented is *semantically* flawed, too.

You wrote:

> ```
> switch(input) {
>     case isalnum(input):
>         ...
> ```

A `switch` statement compares the switch expression -- `input`, in this case -- with each of the `case` expressions, in search of a match.  But `isalnum()` returns an *unspecified* non-zero number when its argument is alphanumeric, and zero otherwise.  There is no reason to expect that `input == isalnum(input)` will be true when `input` is in fact alphanumeric (though it nevertheless might be), whereas you can be certain that that relationship *does* hold for the argument `0`.

Thus, this specific approach would be incorrect even if C permitted `case` expressions to be non-constant.

Answer (score 1):

**switch** statement transfers the control flow of the program to one of the **cases** listed.  That's why you need to assigne constant values to **case**. They are evaluated at compiled time.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to use the switch-case statement, then maybe ditch `isalnum` and just have a bunch of cases for each alphanumeric character with fall-through and then a default case.  Something like:

```
switch(input)
{
    case '0':
    case '1':
    case '2':
```

[...]

```
    case 'z':
        // do something here
        break;
    default:
        // do something else here
        break;
}
```