# PHP page redirection doesn't work properly (based on database role request)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have written my code in php as well as in html for my final project which is the the course registration system for the collage.

**My problem is :**

If I need to redirect the page for one user : it works.

But later, when I use the switch statement for redirect a different pages based on role by retrieving the data from a MySQL database, it doesn't work.

**Here is my code :**

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$db="login";
mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($db);

if(isset($_POST['username'])){

    $username= $_POST['username'];
    $password= $_POST['password'];
    $sql="select * from loginform where username='$username' AND password='$password' ";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $result=mysql_query($role);
    $role="SELECT * FROM loginform  username='$username' AND password='$password'";

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1){
        session_start();
        switch($role)
        {
            case 1:
                $_SESSION['role']='admin';
                header("Location: http://localhost/test/form1.html");
                break;
            case 2:
                $_SESSION['role']='faculty';
                header("Location: http://localhost/test/faculty.html");
                break;
            case 2:
                $_SESSION['role']='student';
                header("Location: http://localhost/test/student.html");
                break;
        }


        echo " You Have Successfully Logged in"; 
        exit();

    }

    else{ 

        $message='Worning !!! ...Incorrect UserName or PassWord';
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
        exit();
        header("Location: http://localhost/test/loginn.php");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: '*doesn't work*' - Is not helpful or something we can work off, do clarify.

Comment: `$role` is a string. You haven't executed the SQL statement. You also have 2 cases with `2` which doesn't make sense. You also try and do mysql_query on `$role` before you've defined it... AND why are you attempting to run the same query twice in succession? There's also the issue of SQL injection because you don't validate or sanitise your inputs.

Comment: What does this have to do with CSS?

Comment: @Helenesh about as much as it has to do with phpmyadmin …

Comment: You need isolate the problem and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a clear explanation of what isn't working with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score -1):

First in your switch statement use true, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829229/why-switchtrue-in-php-with-a-strange-logic) for more info

```
 switch($role)
        {
            case 1:
                $_SESSION['role']='admin';
                header("Location: http://localhost/test/form1.html");
                break;
            case 2:
                $_SESSION['role']='faculty';
                header("Location: http://localhost/test/faculty.html");
                break;
            case 2:
                $_SESSION['role']='student';
                header("Location: http://localhost/test/student.html");
                break;
        }
```

In this switch statement, It will always run the 1st case(case1) because you have not given condition in case(case $role=='something')

```
switch(true)
{
    case $role=='admin':
        header("Location: http://localhost/test/form1.html");
        break;
    case  $role=='faculty':
        header("Location: http://localhost/test/faculty.html");
        break;
    case $role=='student':
        header("Location: http://localhost/test/student.html");
        break;
}
```

just replace your code by mine

Comment: Don't do this. It's dirty and has nothing to do with the question. Also, welcome on SO and thanks for your first contribution ! Be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)